# C++ ifstream throws file not found even though the file exists

Tags: c++, boost, io

I am trying to open a file where the file path is taken as a user input.

However, the C++ runtime says that the file does not exist, but when I hardcode the string, I am able to open the file.

```
std::shared_ptr<Task> Daemon::create_new_task(string &location){
    std::ifstream file;
    std::cout<<"Create new task->"<<location<<endl;
    file.open(location.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    if (!file.is_open())
        perror("Error");
    boost::filesystem::path f("<filepath>");
    std::cerr<<boost::filesystem::exists(f);
    std::stringstream buf;
    buf << file.rdbuf();
    return std::make_shared<Task>(location,buf.str());
}
```

`perror()` says file not found, while the second output is 1.

I tried absolute and relative paths. None of them work.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Difficult to say since we don’t know what the actual contents are and there’s no [mcve] to run

Comment: How am I able to open the file by hardcoding the path? What is wrong in giving a string as a parameter to ifstream?

Comment: Are you really *really* sure it is *exactly* the same string? We can’t tell since we don’t have your code or debugger

Comment: Yes, both the strings are absolute paths.

Comment: @AndyG, no its not a UNC path.
I wrote that small program for this and it seems to work, but when I use it with this large codebase, its not working. Note that create_new_task function is being called from a new thread. Will that affect I/O?

Comment: @Rakshith: I presume that your reference to `location` is invalidated somewhere else before `create_new_task` gets called.

Comment: Then you'll need to create a [mcve] to replicate this.